# Latex titleformat not applied to the section number

Tags: titlesec

I'm changing the structure of the title for a journal publication. I am using *titleformat* as follows

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\itshape}{\thesubsection.}{.7em}{}
```

but the "problem" is that everything in the subsection appears in italics, INCLUDING the number of the subsection. Is there a way to do this without changing the normal font of the number? This is, I want to obtain:

4.1 *Random title*

instead of getting:

*4.1 Random title*

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}{}{\thesubsection.}{.7em}{\itshape}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]